# SQLite.SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Open'

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
 string dbConnectionString = @"Data Source=/Worklight_Sqlite_cplusplus/common.db3;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";
        SQLite.SQLiteConnection sqliteCon = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(dbConnectionString);
        sqliteCon.Open();
```

i using this code try to open the sqlite connection in windows 8 apps, but it get this error!

> Error 1   'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for
>   'Open' and no extension method 'Open' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What exactly type (with namespace) is `SQLite.SQLiteConnection`?

Comment: if i using SQLiteconnection it will come this error

Comment: Error 1 'SQLiteConnection' is an ambiguous reference between 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteConnection' and 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'

Comment: Why do you use two different provider for the same database?

Comment: do you know any good example about this? i get confuse on this topic!

Comment: Finisar has been discontinued from 2006 (I think) so remove that reference and go only with System.Data.SQLite (add a using reference at the beginning of your code)

Comment: after i remove Finisar and change SQLite.SQLiteConnection to SQLiteConnection it get this error 
Error 1 The type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: i saw some of the post said that, windows RT unable to connect to database directly and need use WCF or other web service to make it happen, it's rigth?